Getting non-aggregated steam stats
I've dug through the Better Steam Web API and I can get aggregate stats but I'm hoping to get my non-aggregated stats but I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere but I've heard it's possible.
I read through all of steams documentation and the better web API but came up short.
